# Overlay on a particular image on hover

Tags: jquery, css

I have  2 div's with same class "wrap" when i hover on that div i want to display overlay on that particular div which i hovered

Here is what i tried

```
<div class="wrap" style="display:inline-block">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTQ3aCNvaNCCoxQWqb6PZS1MZZjED5umfE0OPhfjnKsYY8BTSOKY3cIBHzj"  alt="RF1"  class="company-image" />            
            <div class="Image-Overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap" style="display:inline-block">
                     <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTQ3aCNvaNCCoxQWqb6PZS1MZZjED5umfE0OPhfjnKsYY8BTSOKY3cIBHzj"  alt="RF2"  class="company-image" />            
                     <div class="Image-Overlay"></div>
               </div>
```

and here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.wrap').mouseover(function () {
            var x=$(this)
            debugger;
            $('.Image-Overlay').show();                
        }).mouseout(function () {
            $('.Image-Overlay').hide();
        });
    })

</script>
```

and my styles

```
<style>
    .Image-Overlay {
        width: 284px;
        height: 177px;
        background-color: #4baad3;
        z-index: 1;
        opacity: 1;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0.5em;
        display: none;
    }

    .company-image {
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want the respective overlay to show up on top of the image when you hover over the image.

It's important that the parent element be positioned relatively, and the child element (the hover div) be positioned absolutely relative to that parent. The changes in the CSS code below take care of that.

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/C7RPZ/1/

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 284px;
    height: 177px;
    display: inline-block;
}    

.Image-Overlay {
    width: 284px;
    height: 177px;
    background-color: #4baad3;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 1;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.company-image {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.wrap').mouseover(function () {
        $('.Image-Overlay', this).show();                
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $('.Image-Overlay', this).hide();
    });
});
```

### Pure CSS Solution

Update: On second thought, you don't need the JavaScript at all given the problem scope described. You can drop the JavaScript and add the following CSS to the CSS presented above, which will display the overlay when the parent element is hovered (see demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/C7RPZ/2/).

```
.wrap:hover > .Image-Overlay {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.wrap').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('.Image-Overlay').show();
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).find('.Image-Overlay').hide();
    });
})
```

So you use `$(this)` to find what one has been hovered on and then `.find` to get the class `.Image-Overlay` under that `div` (`$(this)`).

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/6VNrD/1/)

Comment: Thanks but the fiddle doesnt work but the script is working fine

Comment: Lol I didnt down voted you i think and really the fiddle is int working not atleast in my chrome,mozilla

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is what you want. Check out my answer.

Comment: this works fine and your too but this isnt working in fiddle donno why

Comment: This solution is going to break if you have anything above it at all, e.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/6VNrD/3/

Comment: @Vivekh I have no idea what you mean. When you hover over an image it gets an overlay, simple as? That's what this does. Its simple jQuery, works in all browsers the same lol.

Comment: This is not the best general solution because the CSS is positioning the overlay at a fixed distance from the top of the browser window, not the top of the parent element.

Comment: @Kyle Oh thats the silly CSS. Sort it out and it will work fine. Its the CSS... Nothing to do with the jQuery.

Comment: That's correct. I didn't mean the problem was with your JavaScript code, but that the Fiddle as a whole didn't represent a good general solution.

Comment: Simple fix (you can do better tho, more to show the problem more then anything) [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/6VNrD/4/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48157/discussion-between-kyle-and-ruddy)

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.wrap').mouseover(function () {
            var x=$(this)
            debugger;
            $('.Image-Overlay', this).show(0);                
        }).mouseout(function () {
            $('.Image-Overlay', this).hide(0);
        });
    })
```

Here is the DEMO.. http://jsfiddle.net/9R9br/3/

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could also do this with only CSS since the methods show() and hide() just change the display property. Anyway your script solution would not work without targeting the one you are hovering.

**CSS only solution**

```
    .wrap {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .wrap:first-child {
        margin-top:0;
    } 
    .wrap img {
        display: block;
    }
    .wrap .Image-Overlay {
         background-color: #4baad3;
         position: absolute;
         left: 0;
         top: 0;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         visibility: hidden;
        }
    .wrap:hover .Image-Overlay {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bm5xL/38/